# php and html convert issue

Tags: php, html

I have a print page in php..inside it I have a html page.. I call a query and with php I'm echoing using a `function(normalizarTexto($query))`:

```
function normalizarTexto($texto) {
    $texto = html_entity_decode($texto);
    $texto = stripcslashes(nl2br(htmlentities($texto)));
    return $texto;
}
```

But it prints the tags!!.. just like the text bellow:

```
Familiares :  Asma Bronquial, Enf. Gástricas <br> Quirurgicos :  Amigdalas, Bazo <br/>Cancer :  Columna, Cuello, Esófago , prueba 4<br/>
```

And if I don't call the function.. it deletes part of the result:

Quirurgicos : Amigdalas, Bazo
Cancer : Columna, Cuello, Esófago , prueba 4
 any idea?

Comment: Isn't the nl2br function inserting the `<br/>`?

Comment: the text in the db bellow the <br/>.. but i dont know why it doesnt read it like html

Comment: I'm just wondering if you need to use the `nl2br` function.

Comment: well just in case another result  brings the \n but i delete that part and... the same

Comment: what does the text look like when it first gets passed to the `normalizerTexto` function?

Comment: This:
Familiares :  Asma Bronquial, Enf. Gástricas <br> Quirurgicos :  Amigdalas, Bazo <br/>Cancer :  Columna, Cuello, Esófago , prueba 4<br/>
and prints the same

Comment: If desired output is no tags or new lines then could you just use `strip_tags( nl2br($texto) );` ?

Comment: i used it.. but no.. the same...